# mMap is null when trying to create a new marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

so, after a year or two i started this project again... by the time it was outdated it worked fine... but since android x came out i wanted to upgrade my application and got stuck on a error i find it funny...

quick brief, i have button that makes me online / offline.. on pressing the button the map should zoom at my curr. location and add a marker.. but here comes the error :

Logcat:

```
    Process: com.app.mk.transport, PID: 22142
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
        at com.app.mk.transport.DriverHome$16$1$1.onComplete(DriverHome.java:1110)
        at com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire$2.onComplete(GeoFire.java:178)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo$6.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:404)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

DriverHome.java ( **Not The whole code** ):

```
    private void setUpAutocomplete() {

        AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = new AutocompleteSupportFragment();

//        final AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment;
//        autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setCountry("MK");

        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.google_open_api));
        }

        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS));
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
                if (location_switch.isChecked()) {

                    destination = place.getAddress();

                    destination = destination.replace(" ", "+");
                    if (destination.contains("+(FYROM)")) {
                        destination = destination.replace("+(FYROM)", "");
                    }
                    mMap.clear();
                    getDirection();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {
                Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this, "" + status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("MITKASIN", "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.driver_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
//         Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_trip_history) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_way_bill) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_update_Info) {

            showDialogUpdateInfo();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sign_out) {
            signOut();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void showDialogUpdateInfo() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DriverHome.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Update Information");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please fill in the informations");

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialog_change_pwd = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_update_information, null);

        final TextInputEditText edt_Name = dialog_change_pwd.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        final TextInputEditText edt_Phone = dialog_change_pwd.findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
        final ImageView image_upload = (ImageView) dialog_change_pwd.findViewById(R.id.image_upload);

        image_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chooseImage();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setView(dialog_change_pwd);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("UPDATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                final android.app.AlertDialog waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder()
                        .setContext(DriverHome.this)
                        .setTheme(R.style.Orange)
                        .setMessage(R.string.waitingDialog_title)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .build();
                waitingDialog.show();


                AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Account account) {
                        String name = edt_Name.getText().toString();
                        String phone = edt_Phone.getText().toString();

                        Map<String, Object> updateInfo = new HashMap<>();

                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
                            updateInfo.put("name", name);

                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))
                            updateInfo.put("phone", phone);

                        DatabaseReference driverInformations = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.user_driver_tbl);
                        driverInformations.child(account.getId())
                                .updateChildren(updateInfo)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        waitingDialog.dismiss();
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this, "Information updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this, "Information update Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private void chooseImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), Common.PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Common.PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri saveUri = data.getData();
            if (saveUri != null) {
                final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                mDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
                mDialog.show();

                String imageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                final StorageReference imageFolder = storageReference.child("images/" + imageName);
                imageFolder.putFile(saveUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                mDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this, "Uploaded !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                imageFolder.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(final Uri uri) {

                                        AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Account account) {
                                                Map<String, Object> avatarUpdate = new HashMap<>();
                                                avatarUpdate.put("avatarUrl", uri.toString());

                                                DatabaseReference driverInformations = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.user_driver_tbl);
                                                driverInformations.child(account.getId())
                                                        .updateChildren(avatarUpdate)
                                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                    Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this, "Uploaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                } else {
                                                                    Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this, "Upload error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {

                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                mDialog.setMessage("Upliaded " + progress + "%");
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }

    private void signOut() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
        else
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        builder.setMessage("Do you want to logout?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //        Paper.init(this);

                        AccountKit.logOut();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DriverHome.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        builder.show();
    }


    private float getBearing(LatLng startPosition, LatLng endPosition) {
        double lat = Math.abs(startPosition.latitude - endPosition.latitude);
        double lng = Math.abs(startPosition.longitude - endPosition.longitude);

        if (startPosition.latitude < endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude < endPosition.longitude)
            return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));

        else if (startPosition.latitude >= endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude < endPosition.longitude)
            return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);

        else if (startPosition.latitude >= endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude >= endPosition.longitude)
            return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);

        else if (startPosition.latitude < endPosition.latitude && startPosition.longitude >= endPosition.longitude)
            return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);

        return -1;
    }

    private void updateFirebaseToken() {



        AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Account account) {

                FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference tokens = db.getReference(Common.token_tbl);

                Token token = new Token(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

                tokens.child(account.getId())
                        .setValue(token);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getDirection() {
        currentPosition = new LatLng(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(), Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude());

        String requestApi = null;
        try {

            requestApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" +
                    "mode=driving&" +
                    "transit_routing_reference=less_driving&" +
                    "origin=" + currentPosition.latitude + "," + currentPosition.longitude + "&" +
                    "destination=" + destination + "&" +
                    "key=" + getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api);
            Log.i("MITKASIN", requestApi);
            mServices.getPath(requestApi)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body());
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject route = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                                    String polyline = poly.getString("points");

                                    polyLineList = decodePoly(polyline);
                                }

                                if (!polyLineList.isEmpty()) {
                                    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                                    for (LatLng latLng : polyLineList)
                                        builder.include(latLng);
                                    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                                    CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 1);
                                    mMap.animateCamera(mCameraUpdate);
//                                    mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
                                }
                                polylineOptiuons = new PolylineOptions();
                                polylineOptiuons.color(Color.GRAY);
                                polylineOptiuons.width(5);
                                polylineOptiuons.startCap(new SquareCap());
                                polylineOptiuons.endCap(new SquareCap());
                                polylineOptiuons.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                                polylineOptiuons.addAll(polyLineList);
                                greyPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptiuons);


                                blackPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                                blackPolylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                                blackPolylineOptions.width(7);
                                blackPolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                                blackPolylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                                blackPolylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                                blackPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(blackPolylineOptions);

                                if (!polyLineList.isEmpty()) {
                                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                            .position(polyLineList.get(polyLineList.size() - 1))
                                            .title("Pickup Location"));
                                }
                                //Animation
                                ValueAnimator polyLineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
                                polyLineAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                                polyLineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                                polyLineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                                        List<LatLng> points = greyPolyline.getPoints();
                                        int percentValue = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                                        int size = points.size();
                                        int newPoints = (int) (size * (percentValue / 100.0f));
                                        List<LatLng> p = points.subList(0, newPoints);
                                        blackPolyline.setPoints(p);

                                    }
                                });

                                polyLineAnimator.start();

                                carMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(currentPosition)
                                        .flat(true)
                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car)));

                                handler = new Handler();
                                index = -1;
                                next = 1;
                                handler.postDelayed(drawPathRunnable, 2000);
//                                mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                            Toast.makeText(DriverHome.this, "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//        mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    }

    private List decodePoly(String encoded) {
        List poly = new ArrayList();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }
        return poly;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PEMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    buildLocationCallback();
                    buildLocationRequest();
                    if (location_switch.isChecked())
                        displayLocation();
                }
        }

    }

    private void setUpLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Request runtime permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{

                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, MY_PEMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        } else {

            buildLocationRequest();
            buildLocationCallback();
            if (location_switch.isChecked())
                displayLocation();
        }


    }

    private void buildLocationCallback() {
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    Common.mLastLocation = location;
                }
                displayLocation();
            }
        };
    }

    private void buildLocationRequest() {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    private void displayLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        Common.mLastLocation = location;

                        if (Common.mLastLocation != null) {
                            if (location_switch.isChecked()) {
                                final double latitude = Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                                final double longitude = Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                                //Update to Firebase


                                AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Account account) {
                                        geoFire.setLocation(account.getId(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {


                                                if (mCurrent != null) {
                                                    mCurrent.remove();
                                                }


                                                mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                                                        .title("Your Location"));

//                                                    Move camera to this position when set to online!
                                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 14.5f));

//                                              Draw animation rotate marker
//                                              rotateMarker(mCurrent, 360, mMap);

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("ERROR", "Cannot get your location");
                        }
                    }
                });

    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);


        try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.style_json));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e("Mitkasin", "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Mitkasin", "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DriverHome.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(DriverHome.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        buildLocationRequest();
        buildLocationCallback();
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

}
```

excuse me for the nasty code tho :D
and sorry if its a dumb question but idk what im missing here ...

Comment: if you try to add marker before your onMapReady is called then mMap will be null and will trigger Null Pointer Exception so make sure you are calling mMap.addMarker(...) only after onMapReady is called

Comment: idk how ... by doing it manually i get other errors ...

Comment: in your onCreate after setContentView first initialise SupportMapFragment then getMapReady only after then start executing other code..,

Comment: try being a bit more specific with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `displayLocation` and `getDirection` methods only after the map has been initialized (i.e. `mMap = googleMap`). Check out related [Null Pointer Exception and getMapAsync Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701736/null-pointer-exception-and-getmapasync-error)

E.g.:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);


    try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.style_json));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e("Mitkasin", "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Mitkasin", "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }

    displayLocation();
    getDirection();
}
```

Hope this helps!